# Python Selenium click on elements inside li

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: I wanna loop all li elements by c]

I be trying to use Selenium webdriver to loop through all list elements by clicking the Edit Button, changing the textarea content, changing the image URL and push the submit button.

```js
ul = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="posts"]') 
items = ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

for index, item in enumerate(items) :
    if index !=  0:
        item.find_element_by_class_name('edit').click()
        item.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea.text").send_keys("Lets have fun")
        item.find_element_by_css_selector("input.img-url").send_keys("http://image.png")
        item.find_element_by_class_name('submit').click()
```

```html
<ul id="posts">
  <li>Banner</li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      <input class="img-url">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       <textarea class="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       <button class="edit"></button> 
       <button class="submit"></button> 
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      <input class="img-url">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       <textarea class="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       <button class="edit"></button> 
       <button class="submit"></button> 
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This does not work. Any suggestion on how to get such a Python selenium loop to work?

Thank you

Comment: What is error message? Could you add sleep after each statement in for loop?

Comment: @Buaban the error message i get is NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"creator"}.

Comment: The error is not inside the code block in your question. You have to find the code where it finds element by `find_element_by_css_selector("creator")`